# Executing different jQuery on browser size (hover vs click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

In my main nav I have a series of submenus. My issue is that on regular browser size I need the menu to open on a hover and on a mobile view I need it to open on a click. I have jQuery that works however I cant turn off the hover on mobile and the click on regular view

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="mainMenu">
     <li>
       ITEM
       <ul class="subMenu">
          <li></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery** (code works but cant turn off on mobile/regular view)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.mainMenu li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeIn();
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeOut();
  });

  $('.mainMenu li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

** ALSO TRIED ** (targeting browser size, code doesnt work anymore)

```
var $browserWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if ($browserWidth > 768) {
      $('.mainMenu li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeIn();
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeOut();
  });
    } else if($browserWidth < 768) {
      $('.mainMenu li').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle();
  });
   }
```

Comment: Do you _need_ to remove the hover event on mobile? As the listener will never fire, you'll actually spend more resources checking the viewport size than you will just letting it go.

Comment: unfortunately I do because when I demo it to clients I have to show on browser resize and it gets ugly when both events fire, otherwise I might be able to get away with letting it go

Comment: Im using CSS to hide and style everything, but on user interaction (click) you have to use jQuery unless there is some sweet new psuedo class i dont know of. Plus CSS3 transitions arent going to work in a lot of browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/).

It details how you can use media queries in JavaScript.

Basically, there's a `matchMedia()` function whose `matches` property will return a boolean when you pass it a css media query.

So in your case:

```
if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches){
  //your desktop code
}
else{
  //your mobile code.
}
```

Comment: obviously won't work in old versions of IE. Perhaps worth having it the other way round, so the media query checks max-width. That way if `window.matchMedia` isn't a function it'll be falsy. Mobile browsers are more likely to have a wider implementation coverage

Comment: hmm, first off thank you. this seems to solve my immediate problem of turning off/on hover vs click, however if i load the browser less then 768 px and then extend it the menu is still bound to the click.... gotta think about a browser resize function

Comment: Ok - that's quite a rare use case so you need to evaluate whether it's worth it as clicking doesn't really detriment the user experience. (remember if you're on a mobile, you can't resize the browser, so it's **only** an 'issue' if you're on a desktop **and** you start small and resize big). All that said, it's possible to register an event listener - scroll further down the page I linked and it tells you how!

Comment: like I said this definately points me in the right direction thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

@Ed Hinchcliffe got me on the right track... this is the answer that ended up working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    menuStuff();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    menuStuff();
});

function menuStuff() {
    var $browserWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if ($browserWidth > 768) {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().bind({
            mouseenter: function (e) {
                $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeIn();
            },
            mouseleave: function (e) {
                $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().fadeOut();
            }
        })
    } else {
        $('.mainMenu > li').unbind().click(function () {
            $(this).find('.subMenu').stop().slideToggle();
        });
    }
}
```